# How to get object_list of another user using ListView in Django?

Tags: python, django-views

I am new to Django and I am creating a simple blog web application. I would like to get the blog post of another user **(not the user that is Authenticated)** using the **get_queryset** Method. I tried the script below but, it shows an empty list on the template. I am able to use get_queryset to show all the blogpost, but my main concern is to show all the blogpost of a specific user **(not the user that is authenticated)**

View.py

```
class OtherUserProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

model = Post
template_name = "core/otheruser.html"

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(OtherUserProfileView, self).get_queryset()
    queryset = queryset.filter(pk=self.user.id)
    return queryset
```

Model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
content = models.TextField()
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
publish = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: How do you know which user's posts to show? Do you want to pass the id of the user you want to show the posts for in the URL?

Comment: Yes. I tried to use that method, but it's not working.

Comment: What did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: I tried the get_queryset method in ListView and filter the pk to self.user.id. You can check the script above. It does not show anything in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the id of the user that you want to filter the queryset by in the url pattern

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/<int:user_id>/', views.OtherUserProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
]
```

In your view you can access the `user_id` from the path via `self.kwargs['user_id']` and use this to filter your queryset

```
class OtherUserProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    model = Post
    template_name = "core/otheruser.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(user_id=self.kwargs['user_id'])
        return queryset
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question. How can we link the user_id to the template? I used this tag to link the user_id, **<a class="text-light " href="{% url 'core:profile' user_id=user.id %}">{{item.user}}</a>**, but instead of showing another user, it return all the post of the authenticated user.

Comment: The view is passed in the context, you should be able to access the passed kwarg from it: `{% url 'core:profile' user_id=view.kwargs.user_id %}`

Comment: I tried the tag above and get an error message whenever I run the server, 

**Tag:**
**<a class="text-light " href="{% url 'core:profile' user_id=view.kwargs.user_id %}">{{item.user}}</a>**

**Error Message:**
**Reverse for 'profile' with keyword arguments '{'user_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$']**